# match.group for array of named groups / strings python

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing strings with following format:

```
ADD id='5' titulo='The Diary of a Young Girl' autor='Anne Frank' 
ADD id='5' titulo='The Diary of a Young Girl' autor='Anne Frank'
SEARCH id='5'
REMOVE id='10'
REMOVE id='5' 
SEARCH id='5' 
ADD id='8' titulo='The Fault in Our Stars' autor='John Green'  
ADD id='14' titulo='Looking for Alaska' autor='John Green' 
SEARCH autor='John Green'
REMOVE autor='Anne Frank'
REMOVE autor='John Green'
SEARCH autor='John Green'
```

Into 4 variables, `operation`, `id`, `title` and `author` using the following regex:

```py
(?P<operation>\w*)?( id='(?P<id>[^']*)')?( titulo='(?P<title>[^']*)')?( autor='(?P<author>[^']*)')?
```

I've tested it on regex101 and it works fine:

[image]

However, matching each named group invidivually seems verbose to me:

```py
def parse_input(input_):
    regex = r"(?P<operation>\w*)?( id='(?P<id>[^']*)')?( titulo='(?P<title>[^']*)')?( autor='(?P<author>[^']*)')?"
    match = re.search(regex, input_)
    
    operation = match.group('operation')
    id_ = match.group('id')
    title = match.group('title')
    author = match.group('author')
    
    return operation, (id_, title, author)
```

Is there some kind of `group_all()` method for passing an array of strings, each one containing the name of my matching groups, that returns the array of matches? Something like:

```py
GROUP_LABELS = ['operation', 'id', 'title', 'author']
regex = r"(?P<operation>\w*)?( id='(?P<id>[^']*)')?( titulo='(?P<title>[^']*)')?( autor='(?P<author>[^']*)')?"

match = re.search(regex, input_)    
matched_groups = match.group_all(GROUP_LABELS)

# or operation, id_, title, author = match.group_all(GROUP_LABELS)
```

Comment: Have you checked [Match.groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups)?

Comment: You won't match correctly if either the title or the name have quotes inside them by using your current regex.

Comment: @ProblemsLoop This is (almost) what I need! It indeed returns all matched groups: `('ADD', " id='5'", '5', " titulo='The Diary of a Young Girl'", 'The Diary of a Young Girl', " autor='Anne Frank'", 'Anne Frank')`, I only need the named ones

Comment: You're correct @lemon! But my use case does guarantees there will be no quotes on titles/names

Comment: @nluizsoliveira then [.groupdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict), which is literally the next entry in the docs

Comment: @ProblemsLoop thanks! That's what I was looking for. `match.groupdict().values()` returns exactly what i need